In Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress, what's the current status of the United States?
Since the Kabane outbreak started in Western Europe and spread across the world, what’s the current status of the United States as of the end of the series (Battle of Unato Castle arc)?
For one, the U.S. at this time is a potential superpower that spans across an entire continent and based on the level of industrialization see in Japan, I think it’s fair to say that the outbreak is roughly post-Civil War. The U.S. military (or at least the Army) would have significant combat experience (albeit against evil, slave-owning traitors and not armored zombies). The U.S. also has significant rail infrastructure to help with logistics. Major terrain features like the Mississippi River, Rocky Mountains, and Appalachian Mountains would give the U.S. an edge up in fighting the Kabane and helping to preserve territory. Also helps that if the Army, Navy, and Marine Corps can halt the Kabane at the Mississippi, they can secure vast stretches of farmland to feed the surviving U.S. population.
However on the other hand, the U.S. received significant numbers of immigrants on the East Coast which definitely had to have had a few infected among them. If those infected made it to New York, then it would only be a matter of time before the East Coast was taken out. It doesn’t help that the US is probably still reeling from the aftermath of the Civil War and with the Kabane running rampant, it could give cause for Neo-Confederates to rearm and take up the mantle of Confederate independence in the face of a federal government that's struggling to fight the Kabane.
